# Logs outgoing emails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, **User** and **Email**

I have an **after_create** callback after user creation that sends a confirmation email to the email address of the user.

**user.rb**

```
after_create :create_confirmation_email

private

    def creation_confirmation_email
      UserMailer.account_create_confirmation(self).deliver
    end
```

The **creation_confirmation_email** above connects to the method in **mailer/user_mailer.rb**

**user_mailer.rb**

```
def account_create_confirmation(user)
    I18n.locale = 'pt'
    @user = user

    mail(from: 'no-reply@miigo.com.br', to: @user.email, subject: 'Bem-vindo ao Miigo') do |format|
      format.text
      format.html
    end
  end
```

My Email model has the following attributes:

```
reply_to: string
first_name: string
last_name :string
subject: string
```

Now what I want is an action that logs the confirmation email information after every delivery.

Can you suggest a workaround or callback for that?

any workarounds will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always write a callback in your `ActionMailer` class, [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks) explains all that.

If you're using Rails 3, IIRC you can add callback functionality to `ActionMailer` classes by including `AbstractController::Callbacks`.

Something like:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include AbstractController::Callbacks

  after_filter :audit_email

  def account_create_confirmation(user)
    @subject = 'Bem-vindo ao Miigo'
    # ...
  end

  def audit_email
    EmailAudit.create(subject: @subject, ...)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. And how can I get the subject of the email by the way? Sorry it's my first time to use action mailer this broad.